# Как в Firebird узнать кто пытался соединится с БД?

Tags: база-данных, безопасность, firebird

Как в Firebird узнать кто пытался соединится с БД?

Вот пример того как узнать кто успешно подключился к БД:

```
create table log (    
  dt  timestamp    not null,
  msg varchar(250) not null);

set term # ;    
create trigger tr_connect on connect
as
begin
  in autonomous transaction do
    insert into log(dt, msg)
    values (current_timestamp, 'user ' || current_user || ' connect.');  
end#
set term ; #
```

В книге "Firebird руководство разработчика баз данных" есть пример "Как запротоколировать попытки соединения с базой данных" но в нем нужно переименовать системную таблицу с пользователями и вместо нее создать представление... Я не хочу лезть в системные таблицы, есть ли другие варианты?